# (Laravel) Routes with multiple parameters break HTML

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-5, laravel-10

I'm kinda new to Laravel and doing a project using the argon dashboard as a base (https://github.com/creativetimofficial/argon-dashboard-laravel) in Laravel 10.8.0. I'm having a problem where routes with multiples parameters break the HTML in the view. For example:

```
Route::get('/alertas', [AlertaController::class, 'show'])->name('alertas');
Route::get('/alertas/historial', [AlertaController::class, 'historial'])->name('alertas.historial');
```

The first route works fine but the second shows only the text with no formatting.
In both cases the returned view is the same, just with a different title:

```
@extends('layouts.basic', ['title' => 'Historial Alertas', 'header' => true])
@section('page')
    <div class="p-3">
        <p>
            <b>Hola Mundo</b>
        </p>

        @can('see-some')
            <p>Esto lo ven los consultores</p>
        @endcan
        @can('see-all')
            <p>Esto lo ven los admins</p>
        @endcan
    </div>
@endsection
```

Where the basic template is:

```
@extends('layouts.app', ['type' => 'basic'])

@section('content')
    @include('layouts.navbars.auth.topnav')
    <div class="row mt-4 mx-4">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card mb-4">
                @if ($header ?? false)
                    <div class="card-header pb-0">
                        <h6>{{ $title }}</h6>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <div class="card-body px-0 pt-0 pb-2">
                    @yield('page')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @include('layouts.footers.auth.footer')
    </div>
@endsection
```

and the app template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/img/favicon.png">
    <title>
        Argon Dashboard 2 by Creative Tim
    </title>

    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="assets/css/opensans.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Nucleo Icons -->
    <link href="./assets/css/nucleo-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="./assets/css/nucleo-svg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
    {{-- <script src="assets/js/42d5adcbca.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> --}}
    <link href="assets/css/nucleo-svg.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- CSS Files -->
    <link id="pagestyle" href="assets/css/argon-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    {{-- misc CSS --}}
    <link href="./assets/css/misc.css" rel="stylesheet" />



</head>

<body class="{{ $class ?? '' }}">

    @if (($type ?? '') == 'basic')
        <div class="min-height-300 bg-primary position-absolute w-100"></div>
        @if ($showside ?? true)
            @include('layouts.navbars.auth.sidenav')
        @endif
        <main class="main-content border-radius-lg">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
        {{-- @include('components.fixed-plugin') --}}

    @else
        @guest
            @yield('content')
        @endguest

        @auth
            @if (in_array(request()->route()->getName(),
                    ['sign-in-static', 'sign-up-static', 'login', 'register', 'recover-password', 'rtl', 'virtual-reality']))
                @yield('content')
            @else
                @if (
                    !in_array(request()->route()->getName(),
                        ['profile', 'profile-static']))
                    <div class="min-height-300 bg-primary position-absolute w-100"></div>
                @elseif (in_array(request()->route()->getName(),
                        ['profile-static', 'profile']))
                    <div class="position-absolute w-100 min-height-300 top-0"
                        style="background-image: url('/img/profile-layout-header.jpg'); background-position-y: 50%;">
                        <span class="mask bg-primary opacity-6"></span>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @include('layouts.navbars.auth.sidenav')
                <main class="main-content border-radius-lg">
                    @yield('content')
                </main>
                @include('components.fixed-plugin')
            @endif
        @endauth
    @endif



    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="assets/js/core/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var win = navigator.platform.indexOf('Win') > -1;
        if (win && document.querySelector('#sidenav-scrollbar')) {
            var options = {
                damping: '0.5'
            }
            Scrollbar.init(document.querySelector('#sidenav-scrollbar'), options);
        }
    </script>
    <!-- Github buttons -->
    <script async defer src="assets/js/buttons.js"></script>
    <!-- Control Center for Soft Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
    <script src="assets/js/argon-dashboard.js"></script>
    @stack('js');
</body>

</html>
```

i believe the relevant errors are:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/core/popper.min.js”. historial:303:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js”. historial:304:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.min.js”. historial:305:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/plugins/smooth-scrollbar.min.js”. historial:306:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/buttons.js”. historial:317:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/alertas/assets/js/argon-dashboard.js”.
```

I've tried changing the routes to see if the problem was the view itself and determined the problem  is caused by the route having multiple parameters, views which otherwise work fine always break if I add another parameter to the route, even if it's something like 'users/{id}'.

I would be very thankful if anyone could provide any help with this problem, and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the actual problem is with your `app.blade.php` file where you need to use [laravel asset helper](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/helpers#method-asset) to link your assets instead of hard-coded link. please try below method to link your all assets.

```
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/argon-dashboard.js')}}"></script>
```